# how to generate a dynamic url using ajax in jquery in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
        $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'script', 
        url: '/admin/my_page/'+mypage_id+'/pages/show_page',
        style : "inherit",
        dataType: 'script',                                                         
        data: "submitcheckdata="+mypage_id,
        complete: function() { 

        }            
  });
```

THere are two problems :

- Lhow do i fetch variables from my pages controller and pass to page.js file?
  if i have the id,
- then how do i generate dynamic url using ajax.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to include your JS within your HTML ( I will use HAML in my example )

```
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'script', 
    url: "/admin/my_page/#{mypage_id}/pages/show_page",
    // ^ Note the use of double quotes here.
    style : "inherit",
    dataType: 'script',                                                         
    data: "submitcheckdata=#{mypage_id}",
    complete: function() { 

    }            });
```

Sometimes I feel like this gets kind of ugly putting HTML and Javscript together. It's like mixing your dessert with your dinner. So I include it as a separate partial especially if you have a lot Rails dependent JS.

Another technique I employed once before was I sent out an initial AJAX request that would retrieve what dynamic content I would need to produce a second AJAX request that would be effectually, what you have as an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it in the view as js variable

```
<script>
  var mypage_id = <%= @page.id %>;
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,but is there any other way by which we can get the params in JS.